# Magento API trying to bulk update price and quantity via async endpoint "Request does not match any route"

Tags: php, magento

Trying to bulk update price and quantity. API works fine on individual product updates using `products` endpoint. Trying to do so in bulk as we have 1000s to update daily. Magento version 2.4.3-p1

```
$url = MAGENTO_API_URL . 'async/bulk/V1/products/bySku';
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($productUpdates));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $response;
```

result:

> Request does not match any route

Is there something I need to install or enable?